# SIGABRT When Mallocing Space for Element in Pointer Array

Tags: c, string, gdb, malloc, valgrind

I'm attempting to have an array of strings in c where each string has the correct amount of chars allocated for it, however, I am receiving the following error:

```
sort: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a42428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
```

I ran the program in GDB and the error occurs on the second line entry ex if the input is: "this\nis\n"
 the program fails when processing "is." The line causing the error is

```
words[j]=(char *)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Here words[j] is a pointer pointer array at location 1. 'i' is the number of chars in the input string (in this case the input was "is" so i is 2).

I also ran the program through Valgrind which quits on the first word with the following error message:

```
==15272== Invalid write of size 8
==15272==    at 0x4C326CB: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15272==    by 0x400A16: main (sort.c:59)
==15272==  Address 0x52064c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 alloc'd
==15272==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15272==    by 0x4009AD: main (sort.c:54)
==15272==
```

The line of code associated with 54 is again:

```
words[j]=(char *)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
```

The line associated with 59 is:

```
memcpy(words[j],buffer,sizeof(buffer)+1);
```

Where buffer is an array of size 1024 containing the user input string: "is\0"

As requested, here is more of the code:

```
 char **words=malloc(1024*sizeof(*words));
 if(!words){
     perror("The word array could not be allocated in memory.");
     exit(7);
 }
 int word_count=0;
 char buffer[1024];
 c= ' ';
 for(int j=0;j<1024;j++){
     memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
     for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
         c=getchar();
         if(c==EOF || c== '\n'){
             //printf("c is %c buffer is %s\n",c,buffer);
             buffer[i]='\0';
             word_count++;
             words[j]=(char *)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
             if(!words[j]){
             perror("The word could not be allocated in memory.");
             exit(7);
             }
             memcpy(words[j],buffer,sizeof(buffer)+1);
             words[j][sizeof(buffer)+1]='\0';
             break;
         }
         buffer[i]=c;
     }
     if(c==EOF){
         break;
     }
     else continue;
 }
 }
```

Comment: When showing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it's minimal, that it's complete, and verifiable. And that it doesn't contain line numbers (especially in the wrong order!) If you need to show us a special line, then use comments in the code to tell us about it.

Comment: Better? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I need to see more of the overall body of code.  At a minimum, the computation of `i` and moving data in the new node.  However, this runtime error isn't actually caused by malloc(), it is caused by the heap being corrupted, a result of incorrect pointer operations before calling malloc.  Maybe long before.

Comment: I added more relevant code. @wallyk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The line associated with 59 is:
>
> ```
> memcpy(words[j],buffer,sizeof(buffer)+1);
> ```
>
> Where buffer is an array of size 1024 containing the user input string: "is\0"

This is the bug.  `sizeof(buffer)+1` is 1025; you are copying 1025 chars, regardless of the length of the input string.  You only allocated space for `i+1` chars, so `i+1` chars is how much you should copy.

Comment: Thank you for saving my systems programming grade. I don't have much to offer, but please accept this Panda video as a sign of my gratitude: https://www.trendsmap.com/twitter/tweet/973194292717129728